# Kony project properties window

Tags: temenos-quantum

When copy a Kony project from another mac laptop to my mac laptop and trying to open the properties window it doesn't appear at all, shall edit/remove any xml files?

Comment: only importing the project from visualiser or kony studio should do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, copying the physical folder directly doesn't work sometimes. It may happen due to visualizer version mismatch.

1. You need to use File -> Export option from the existing machine. It creates a .zip file with you project contents.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbuSE.png)
2. Use File -> import option in the new machine to import the project.

Note: Project created using lower version of Kony Visualizer can be imported into higher versions. But the reverse is not possible.
e.g. Project created using Kony Visualizer 7.2 cannot be opened in 7.1 or 7.0 versions.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Don't just copy and paste the code. That won't work because of the underlying configuration files of each installation. Instead

1. Go to File>Export on your source workstation. This will generate a zip file for you.
2. Then copy that zip file to the target workstation.
3. In your target workstation go to File>Import.

You'll find that this works nicely and you won't have this issue.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to root folder of your project.
2. Zip it and move to other mac
3. Make sure that project.properties is not corrupted.